# Count number of rows that span the values in a vector for each item in the vector

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to count the number of rows in a dataframe that contain value pairs that span the values in a separate vector for each item in that separate vector.

For instance, If I have vector p:

```
> p=seq(1,7,1);p
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

and dataframe se:

```
> s=c(1,2,2,5)
> e=c(5,7,11,22)
> se=data.frame(s,e);se
  s  e
1 1  5
2 2  7
3 2 11
4 5 22
```

I would like to know how many rows in 'se' overlap each item in 'p'. The output I would expect should look similar to this:

```
1 1
2 3
3 3
4 3
5 4
6 3
7 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `sapply` to check for each value in `p`.

```
result <- data.frame(p, overlap=sapply(p,function(x) sum(x >= se$s & x <= se$e)))
result

#  p overlap
#1 1       1
#2 2       3
#3 3       3
#4 4       3
#5 5       4
#6 6       3
#7 7       3
```

Comment: Awesome! Thankyou!

Comment: You could make this slightly more efficient by only calculating the sums once - `colSums(sapply(p, function(x) x >= se$s & x <= se$e))`